# How to set UISearchBar in maps application in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, maps, mkmapview, uisearchbar

I am new using swift and I want to make an application that uses maps and I'm trying to include a search bar(**`UISearchBar`**) but when I try to make a function that makes the search I get an error in one line. Here's the code:

```
func performSearch(){
    matchingItems.removeAll()
    let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
    request.naturalLanguageQuery = searchText.text
    request.region = mapView.region

    let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
    search.startWithCompletionHandler{
         (response: MKLocalSearchResponse!, error: NSError!) in
         for item in response.mapItems{
             print("Item name = \(item.name)")
             print("Latitude = \(item.placemark.location!.coordinate.latitude)")
             print("Longitude = \(item.placemark.location!.coordinate.longitude)")
      }
   }
}
```

I get the error in the `**startWithCompletionHandler**` part that says:

> "Cannot convert value of type '(MKLocalSearchResponse!, NSError!) ->
>   ()' to expected argument type 'MKLocalSearchCompletionHandler'".

Can you tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the definition of [MKLocalSearchCompletionHandler](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKLocalSearch/#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/MKLocalSearchCompletionHandler), you can see that its declaration is not exactly the same :

```
typealias MKLocalSearchCompletionHandler = (MKLocalSearchResponse?, NSError?) -> Void
```

Just replace your code by :

```
func performSearch(){
    let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
    request.naturalLanguageQuery = searchText.text
    request.region = mapView.region
    let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
    search.startWithCompletionHandler{
        (response: MKLocalSearchResponse?, error: NSError?) in
        if let items = response?.mapItems
        {
            for item in items{
                print("Item name = \(item.name)")
                print("Latitude = \(item.placemark.location!.coordinate.latitude)")
                print("Longitude = \(item.placemark.location!.coordinate.longitude)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you unmark it as correct if it resolved your issue ?

Comment: Hello - this code no longer works - it gets the same error as the original one listed above.  Is there a 2022 fix for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The exclamation marks on your code need to be changed
instead of this:

```
(response: MKLocalSearchResponse!, error: NSError!) in
```

use this:

```
(response: MKLocalSearchResponse?, error: NSError?) in
```

Useful links:
[MKLocalSearchCompletionHandler](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKLocalSearch/#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/MKLocalSearchCompletionHandler)

Hope it helps